# How can I add range markers in a Google chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using the google chart library to draw charts in an angular application. I have created an area chart, however, I need to show two markers inside the chart area representing `min` and `max` limit like this:
[image: intended chart representation]

According to google developer chart documentation, there is an old way to show a range area using image chart which is long been deprecated. I am using the most recent API but couldn't find a clean way of achieving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use a `ComboChart`, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57808203/5090771)...